# How do i display category module on a custom page in opencart?

Tags: php, smarty, opencart

I am new in php so i don't know what to do!
For opencart I created a custom page for products.I want to add category module which is provided ready by opencart but i don't know how. Any idea how to add category module to my custom page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your custom page to a layout that displays the categories module.

Alternately you can create a new layout just for your custom page, then add the category module to your new layout.

Comment: How I can assign my custom page to a layout?

Comment: ok I found how http://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-1-5-x-how-to-add-new-layout-and-assign-a-module-to-a-page-using-it.html

Answer (score -1):

No need to add a custome page for displaying category. If you entered category from the admin side then front side will be display your category...

Comment: i want to display category module(the one on the left) on my custom page. i created the custom page: testpage and on that page i echo 'hiii'. but on the left i want the category module. i add the same code as the one provided in opencart(product.php in controller folder) but still no luck

Comment: You need to add the category module to whatever layout you used for your custom page.